# Python: Read CSV from S3 bucket with `import csv`

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3

I am currently trying to read a `.csv` directly from an AWS S3 bucket. However, I am always receiving a `FileNotFoundError`. Weirdly after I can actually see the content of the .csv file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<console>", line 1, in <module> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b',event_id,ds,yhat,yhat_lower,yhat_upper\n0,277,2019-09-04 07:14:08.051643,0.3054256311115928,0.29750667741533227,0.31441960581142636\n'
```

**Here my code:**

```
BUCKET_NAME = 'fbprophet'
FORECAST_DATA_OBJECT = 'forecast.csv'
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=settings.ML_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.ML_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
)
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=FORECAST_DATA_OBJECT)
data = obj['Body'].read()

with open(data, newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(io.BytesIO(csvfile), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

And here some content of my .csv file. I ideally I could access each row as a dictionary with row['event_id']. E.g. to access **yhat** I could just write row['event_id']['yhat]. But currently, that's not how it works at all.

```
    event_id    ds  yhat    yhat_lower  yhat_upper
0   277 2019-09-04 7:14:08  0.3054256311    0.2975066774    0.3144196058
0   178 2019-09-28  0.3454256311    0.2275066774    0.3944196058
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just get rid of `with open(data, newline='') as csvfile:`
because `open` expects a name of a file on your local filesystem.
You should pass `data` to `io.BytesIO` directly.

```
BUCKET_NAME = 'fbprophet'
FORECAST_DATA_OBJECT = 'forecast.csv'
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=settings.ML_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.ML_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
)
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=FORECAST_DATA_OBJECT)
data = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
spamreader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(data), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in spamreader:
    print(', '.join(row))
```

**Edit**: Apparently `csv.reader` expects strings, not bytes,
so you need to decode the response and wrap data in `is.StringIO` instead.

Comment: Hi taras, I tried that but there I receive the following error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)` Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
spamreader = csv.reader(io.BytesIO(data), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
for row in spamreader:
    print(', '.join(row))
```